# fglrx drivers on 14.04.4

Tags: 14.04, radeon, amd-graphics, fglrx

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.4 to use fglrx driver with my AMD GPU HD 8750m (i have hybrid graphic card intel+AMD). I didn't update anything (also while install) and when I'm switching to fglrx driver it crashes system, even when I switch Xorg it's not the same anymore - can't even watch a video, browser don't work etc. Could you help me with this issue? Maybe should I update system but without new Kernel and Xorg drivers?

Comment: I believe that the kernel 4 in 14.04.4 does not support the fglrx drivers anymore. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver)

Comment: if I run `sudo apt-get remove linux-generic-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial` it should work?

Comment: The Ubuntu 14.04.4 kernel/xorg have not been supported since August 2016, so if you are still using those, you would be missing many security updates. It's the 14.04.5 stack that is based on xenial, which breaks compatibility with fglrx. If you want a supported kernel/xorg that works with fglrx on 14.04, you need to revert to the original kernel and xorg stacks. You might also want to try a live ISO of 16.04.4 to see if the latest kernel/xorg with amdgpu works better with your card than what is available in 14.04.